# Social icons on my index page don't take visitor to specific site(s)

Tags: headers, custom-header

[**My index page**](https://danscartoons.com) has three button on top upper right corner. They are Facebook, Twitter and RSS.

I have accessed my `header.php` to add the appropriate URL's for both Facebook & Twitter (I did not add RSS feed as of yet) below is a screenshot of what I have so far:

[image: screenshot]

However, the icons aren't going to the appropriate URL, why is that?

Comment: How inappropriate it is? Eg: Where you go after click on Facebook?

Comment: not sure I understand your response. Is there anything in that code I should delete? I mean, take out? Let me know

Comment: Sorry, ok, first, please view source of page output to make sure your code work.
About the previous comment, I mean when you click on Facebook link for example, what URL does appear in address bar? I can be the problem with CSS.

Comment: Can you please click link to my index page now? I noticed they are working and wonder if they are working on your browser? Let me know. It is weird, because I did nothing to the settings in my wp admin. I am wondering if it is because my site needed to be revisited by the search engines again? Let me know what you think. Thanks for your feedback, I appreciate you. If you need me to chack any links for you on your site, let me know....I am in the states

Comment: It's worked on mine.

Comment: thanks...I discovered they are all working now...I don't know why after I did add proper data that those icons did not actually work in the first place....it seems like it took a day for them to "activate" - why, I have no idea. I went into my wp-admin, initially edited in the "header.php" and then updated....however, they didn't work. While waiting for responses here, I later discovered they DIOD work (about a day later)....cannot understand that. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the OP's answer that was posted within the comments:

> I went into my `wp-admin`, initially edited in the `header.php` and then updated it. However, they didn't work. While waiting for responses here, I later discovered they did work (about a day later), cannot understand that.

This sounds like it was a caching issue which took a day for the results to appear. In the future, be sure to clear the cache in both your web browser and your website to make sure that you changes go through.

Comment: I appreciate your emphasizing I should empty cache....thank you! Making mental note of it

Comment: Sure thing. Be sure to click the checkmark next to this answer to indicate that your question has been resolved. We're trying to close out question that have been answered but never approved by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

OK I clicked grey checkmark to turn it green!